# High latency over time

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, node-modules, google-cloud-run

I am running a nodejs application which uses redis and sequelize library(to connect mysql).The application runs on cluod run. Initally morning when the transactions starts the response is fast.But as time passes by, the response time for 50 percentile is less than 1 sec. Whereas my 99 percentile and 95 percentile response time is less than (15 secs) resulting in very high latency. But memory stays at 20% out of 512 MB. Also my 95 percentile and 99 percentile is more than 80% cpu but my 50 percentile is less than 30%. What could be the issue? Is it due to memory paging or any other rasons?

Comment: Could it be related to DB? Or it's related only to the application and the time passed from the startup moment?

Comment: @Anatoly: its the time passed from the start up

Comment: You could have latency in your database (index missing?) or maybe have connection errors that can increase the latency. Are you sure that you log all the errors?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere: my dtabase queries are in few milliseconds. So i dont see a problem there

Comment: But my memory stays consistent at 21% of 512MB. Could it be a problem, once it freezes throttles CPU?

Comment: There is no reason the CPU throttled if you don't perform operation after having sent the HTTP response.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please gather when CPU throttled down,. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere: is there a way to check if something is being run after response is sent.

Comment: I don't know. If you have the knowledge on the code, it's easy. If you run third party packages, it's harder. A solution is to set the throttling to false and to have a try to see if it's better or not. Use Always ON cpu, or this parameter in the gcloud CLI `--no-cpu-throttling`

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere we tested in our dev without cloud run..the response time increase because of axios..

Comment: A library memory leak I guess. It happens often....